# Atualizar uma variável PHP dentro de uma função Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, setinterval

Estou utilizando o seguinte código para exibir a hora atual do servidor:

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
  function segundoAtual() {
    var n = <?php
 date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
 $cH = date('G');
 $cM = date('i');
 $cS = date('s');
 echo ($cH*60*60)+($cM*60)+$cS;
 ?>;
     var segundosInicio = inicioYujiaLynxA+(-difLynx);

c = (( n - segundosInicio + duraYujia ) % duraYujia ) / duraYujia;

i = Math.floor((mapYujia.length * 2 - 2) * c);
if( i >= mapYujia.length ) i = mapYujia.length * 2 - i - 1;

var pin = document.getElementById('pin');
pin.style.left = (mapYujia[i][0]/600*100) + '%';
pin.style.top  = (mapYujia[i][1]/757*100) + '%';
  }
    segundoAtual();
    setInterval(segundoAtual, 1);
</script>
```

As variáveis `segundosInicio`, `inicioYujiaLynxA` e `difLynx` estão definidas em outro arquivo, chamado através de `<script src="servers.js"></script>` no início do documento.

A variável `segundoAtual` define a posição de um elemento (pin), sobre um mapa...

O resultado é obtido em segundos desde a meia noite de hoje.

Ou setInterval não está sendo executado para atualizar a hora, ou a variável só poderá ser atualizada se a página for recarregada?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apenas quando a página for atualizada, ideal seria vc fazer o seguinte:

Criar uma página PHP que retorna o horário do servidor.
Crie uma segunda página com o seu javascript chamando via ajax essa página que retorna o horário. Assim você pode atualizar seu elemento javascript.

test.php

```
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
        update();
});
function update(){
setInterval(
    function() {

$.ajax({
    url: "hora.php",
    success: function(n){
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
    segundoAtual(parseInt(n))
    }
});

    },

1000);
}

    function segundoAtual(n) {

        var segundosInicio = inicioYujiaLynxA+(-difLynx);

c = (( n - segundosInicio + duraYujia ) % duraYujia ) / duraYujia;

i = Math.floor((mapYujia.length * 2 - 2) * c);
if( i >= mapYujia.length ) i = mapYujia.length * 2 - i - 1;

var pin = document.getElementById('pin');
pin.style.left = (mapYujia[i][0]/600*100) + '%';
pin.style.top  = (mapYujia[i][1]/757*100) + '%';
  }

</script>
```

hora.php

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$cH = date('G');
$cM = date('i');
$cS = date('s');
echo ($cH*60*60)+($cM*60)+$cS;
?>
```

Comment: @NilberVittorazii nunca utilizei ajax em nenhum projeto. Poderia me dar mais instruções de como proceder? Edit: obrigado, vou tentar seguir o que passou.

Comment: @NilberVittorazii obrigado por informar o que fazer, realmente atualiza agora. Mas fiquei completamente perdido em como adaptar ao projeto, antes era apenas javascript, e o restante da função não sei como incluir junto da sua.

Comment: @NilberVittorazii fiz a edição da pergunta incluindo todo código que estou utilizando, poderia me instruir novamente? obrigado desde já.

Comment: A variável "N" está sendo usada onde no seu javascript? não vi nada referenciando ela.... "var n = <?php"... explique o que deseja fazer ao final disso tudo...

Comment: Desculpe, esqueci de alterar o código quando passei aqui para a pergunta, o "N" está em "c = (( N - segundosInicio + duraYujia ) % duraYujia ) / duraYujia;" e representa o segundo atual para que o "pin" se movimente no mapa de acordo com a hora do servidor.

Comment: atualizei novamente, lembrando que o código não está completo, apenas juntei onde deve estar a minha parte junto com a sua..

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente. Para fazer a junção das duas funções utiliza-se o parseInt?

Comment: o parseInt é apenas para garantir que se o resultado do PHP venha como texto ele converte para inteiro, para vc pode usar como número na sua função javascript